# IOException issues

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory

We started using artifactory in the company I work for a little while ago. Now new member joined my development team. When he tried to build our application, he got the following error:

```
Failure to transfer com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:pom:7.1.11 from   http://192.168.0.12/artifactory/repo was 
cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update    interval of repo has elapsed or 
updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:pom:7.1.11 from/
to repo (http://192.168.0.12/artifactory/repo): java.io.IOException: Remotely Closed
```

But i saw that this artifact is present on artifactory and also I have the same configuration of his and I'm able to work correctly.

He is also able to see the artifact at the following url:

```
http://192.168.0.12/artifactory/repo/com/vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin/7.1.11/vaad‌​in-maven-plugin-7.1.11.pom
```

Comment: Can he get the pom in the browser?
`http://192.168.0.12/artifactory/repo/com/vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin/7.1.11/vaadin-maven-plugin-7.1.11.pom`

Comment: Try running Maven with the -e -X options, maybe the debug information can help. You can also use the -U to force maven to try and resolve again